# Python issue: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' during web scraping

Tags: python, function, loops, beautifulsoup, scraper

I am attempting to scrape some info from a website. I was able to successfully scrape the text that i was looking for, but when I try to create a function to append the texts together, i get a TypeError of an unhashable type.

Do you know what may be happening here? Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Here is the code in question:

```
records = []
for result in results:
    name = result.contents[0][0:-1]
```

and here is the code in entirety, for reproducing purposes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://skinsalvationsf.com/2012/08/updated-comedogenic-ingredients-list/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'valign':'top'})

records = []
for result in results:
    name = result.contents[0][0:-1]
```

A sample of `results` items:

```
<td valign="top" width="33%">Acetylated Lanolin <sup>5</sup></td>,
<td valign="top" width="33%">Coconut Butter<sup> 8</sup></td>,
...
<td valign="top" width="33%"><sup> </sup></td>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That error message almost always means that you think you have a list (or other sequence), but you actually have a dict (or other mapping). The error message could be a little nicer, but the point is: it doesn't make any sense to slice a range out of a dict.

Comment: As for how to fix it… well, that depends on what's in `contents[0]`, what you thought was in there, and what you were hoping that `[0:-1]` to select.

Comment: `>>> first_result = results[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'results' is not defined` This is what I get :|

Comment: You haven't initialized `results` before using it as `results[0]`.

Comment: Also, it would be much better as a [mcve] if you just took out the `requests` and `bs4` parts and just directly gave us `results = [<some Python list literal that reproduces the problem>]`.

Comment: @pynewbee Can you clarify the problem here?

Comment: @shubham sorry about that. i updated the code to include results. results = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'valign':'top'})

Comment: @abarnert the code has been updated to include the results. results = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'valign':'top'}) thank you!

Comment: When I run this, I get a 403 error from the web server, which of course means the soup ends up empty, results is empty, and your error cannot be reproduced. Again, it would be much better if you strip out the `requests` and `bs4` stuff and just give us a sample string for `results` that demonstrates the problem. Please read [mcve] if it's not clear how to narrow your problem down; it really is helpful.

Comment: @abarnert my post is updated to show the sample string for results. thank you!

Comment: `results= <td valign="top" width="33%">Acetylated Lanolin <sup>5</sup></td>` is not even valid code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some of your collected results the `contents` contains no text, but only `Tag` objects, so you get a `TypeError` when trying to select a slice from the `Tag`'s attributes dictionary.

You can catch such errors with a try-except block,

```
for result in results:
    try:
        name = result.contents[0][0:-1]
    except TypeError:
        continue
```

Or you could use [`.strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) to select only `NavigableString` contents,

```
for result in results:
    name = list(result.strings)[0][0:-1]
```

---

But it seems like it's only the last item that has no text content, so you could just ignore it.

```
results = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'valign':'top'})[:-1]

for result in results:
    name = result.contents[0][:-1]
```

Comment: the second method of .strings works! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To understand why you're getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'` read [t.m.adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7811673/t-m-adam). In a nutshell in the last iteration `result` variables points to a `bs4.element.Tag` object instead of `bs4.element.NavigableString`.

Below is the working solution with try-except block used since the last 2 `<td>` elements in the list contain no "stripped_strings" and would produce `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`.

**Code: (Python 3.6+ if you want to use [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/))**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://skinsalvationsf.com/2012/08/updated-comedogenic-ingredients-list/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36'}
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

tds = soup.find_all('td')
for td in tds:
    try:
        ingredient, rating = td.stripped_strings
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        print(f'{ingredient} -> {rating}')
```

**Output:**

```
Acetylated Lanolin -> 5
Coconut Butter -> 8
...
Xylene -> 7
Octyl Palmitate -> 7
```

---

You could also get rid of the entire `try-except-else` and omit the last 2 `<td>`:

```
tds = soup.find_all('td')[:-2]
for td in tds:
    ingredient, rating = td.stripped_strings
    ...
```

However, the maintainers of the website might decide to add or delete some ingredients, causing the code to miss some ingredients.

Comment: this method works also! thank you for the explanation!